# Why does a CRC detect burst errors of longer than r+1 bits independently of burst length?

Tags: error-correcting-codes, crc

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49752754/proof-of-crc-burst-error-detection-checksum-result) it is stated that a CRC detects burst errors of length greater than the CRC length with probability $1-2^{-r}$, where $r$ is the length of the CRC.

Why is there no dependence on the length of the burst?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CRC could have any of $2^r$ possible values. If you have an error burst where k >= r bits have random bit values, then the CRC of these k bits has one of $2^r$ possible values (because the CRC has r bits), of which one is correct. So you get the correct CRC by pure coincidence with probability $2^{-r}$.

For smaller errors (less than r bit) we would try to design the CRC so it cannot ever be correct.

Comment: This answer is incorrect in at least three aspects. First, there is a non-zero number of false positives for _k > r_, not _k ≥ r_. An _r_-bit burst error is always detected. Second, there is in fact a dependence on _k_ (see my answer). The probability of a false positive is _2^-r_ only in the limit of _k_ going to infinity. Third, there is no "design" required. Any _r_-bit CRC will detect all bursts of errors of _r_ or fewer bits.

Answer (score 1):

There is a dependence on the length. For an *n*-bit CRC and a *k*-bit burst error, the probability of a false positive is *(2<sup>max(k – n, 0)</sup> – 1) / (2<sup>k</sup> – 1)*. One minus that is the probability of a *k*-bit burst error detection.

In the limit, you get *1 – 2<sup>-n</sup>*.